# How can I apply a shutter effect to a TextureView Camera2 preview

Tags: android, android-camera2

I have used a TextureView to preview image capture in an android application. This works okay, but I'm attempting to provide user feedback that images have been captured. I would like briefly hide the image preview, and then resume normal preview to provide that feedback.

I have failed attempting to push a blank image to the TextureView, and I've also failed to use the setVisibility() attribute (INVISIBLE and GONE) to momentarily hide the TextureView itself - this attribute has no visible effect. How else can I implement this feedback?

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Lukas' answer, I also have a full black view on top of the texture view. When user presses the shutter button, this black view will fade in and then fade out. I find this animation to be closer to a real shutter effect that the phone's native camera has.

```xml
<TextureView
    android:id="@+id/view_finder"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    
<View
    android:id="@+id/camera_overlay"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

```kotlin
view.captureButton.setOnClickListener {
    val fadeOutAnimation = AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f).apply {
        duration = 250
        setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
            override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) {
            }

            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {
                view.captureOverlay.alpha = 0.0f
                view.captureOverlay.isVisible = false
            }

            override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) {
            }
        })
    }
    val fadeInAnimation = AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f).apply {
        duration = 20
        setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
            override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) {
            }

            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {
                view.captureOverlay.alpha = 1.0f
                Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                    view.captureOverlay.startAnimation(fadeOutAnimation)
                }, 20)
            }

            override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) {
                view.captureOverlay.isVisible = true
            }
        })
    }
    view.captureOverlay.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation)

    /**
     * Capture image here
     */
}
```

Comment: How can I use it separately as a function so that it can be used in other places? And I am wondering how to make a file in res-anim and use it.

Answer (score 1):

I did it by using a simple view that is exactly as big as your camera preview that is invisible per default and showing it for 100 ms when a picture gets taken.

```
camera?.takePicture(shutterCallback, null, takePictureCallback)

private val shutterCallback = Camera.ShutterCallback {
    shutterEffectView.setVisible()
    val handler = Handler()
    val runnable = Runnable { shutterEffectView.setGone() }
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 100)
}
```

This code is kotlin and I am using the shutter callback because I am using the old camera API. With the camera2 API I think you have to use [this callback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback.html)